# How to add retrofit data in Material Drawer using .withBadge

Tags: android, retrofit, drawer

I am using Material Drawer in android. I want to show my pending total qty instead of "0". It comes from server. Here is my code;

```
SecondaryDrawerItem drawerPending = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_pending);
Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_pending).withIcon(MaterialDesignIconic.Icon.gmi_truck).withBadge("0"),
                .build();



user = StoreUtil.getInstance().selectFrom("users");
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getShippingList(user.getId(), new Callback<MyOrderList>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MyOrderList myOrderList, Response response) {
              //  txt_pending_totalQty.setText(myOrderList.getNotshippinglist().toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Okay so what is the problem?

Comment: instead **.withBadge("0"),** I would like to add data from **myOrderList.getNotshippinglist().toString()**. ("0") is static.